# Website - Connecting to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am aware this is a stupid question, but to connect to a database that is on my local server, do i connect via this code:

```
mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass")
```

so using localhost connection. This seems to make sense, as it is sending a message to the host computer to connect to it's local database.

or do i use this piece of code:

```
mysql_connect("Ipaddress","user","pass")
```

This also makes sense to me somehow. Which one do i use for my website which i am hosting at home.

EDIT: obviously I want it so that people from all over the world enter information, and it is sent to a database. It isn't meant to be used by me.

Comment: `mysql_*` ---> deprecated. Use PDO. *localhost* gets resolved to 127.0.0.1, which is your loopback address. If the database is on the same system as the webserver, use `localhost`, else use the IP address of the database host.

Comment: Thank you, i just wanted it to be cleared up as i was unsure. I am very new to MySQL and running a webserver.

Comment: a better place for you to start is manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: when people viewing your page, then, the page is hosted on your local machine, then, the database request came from local files from your local machine, so in all cases, pages that are on your local machine connecting to the db not outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to do this is:

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    };
?>
```

This is what I personally use, there are other ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use localhost:

You could something like this:

```
<?php
$mysql = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
if(!mysql){
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

//code her
mysql_close(mysql) //stops the connection
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your database will most likely be stored on the same server as your program, you should put localhost.
Anyway, take some time to learn about PDO. It's more secure, cleaner and actually easier to use.